# Printing linked list using recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, tree, linked-list, nodes

I'm able to print my linked list:

```
|
|-> [ID: 3] Poetry
|   |
|   |-> [ID: 3] Notes 3
|   |   
|   |-> [ID: 2] Notes 2
|   |   
|   |-> [ID: 1] Notes 1
|   |   
|
|-> [ID: 2] Diet
|   |
|   |-> [ID: 2] Diet 2
|   |   
|   |-> [ID: 1] Diet 1
|   |   
|
|-> [ID: 1] Program
```

With the following function that I wrote:

```
void printn(NODE *handle)   //only 2 depths allowed
    {
    NODE *copy_handle = NULL; 
    NODE *depth1 = NULL;
    NODE *depth2 = NULL;

    for( copy_handle = handle ; copy_handle != NULL ; copy_handle = copy_handle->pNext  )
        {
        printf("|\n|-> [ID: %d] %s\n", copy_handle->id, copy_handle->pLabel);

        if(copy_handle->pInner != NULL )
            {
            printf("|\t|\n");
            for(depth1 = copy_handle->pInner ; depth1 != NULL ; depth1 = depth1->pNext  )
                {
                printf("|\t|-> [ID: %d] %s\n", depth1->id, depth1->pLabel);

                if(depth1->pInner != NULL )
                    {
                    printf("|\t|\t|\n");
                    for(depth2 = depth1->pInner ; depth2 != NULL ; depth2 = depth2->pNext  )
                        {
                        printf( "|\t|\t|-> [ID: %d] %s\n", depth2->id, depth2->pLabel);
                        }
                    }

                printf("|\t|\t\n");
                } 
            }
        }

    }
```

This function however is limited in that I'm only able to print a child of the node and a child of that child or as I call it in my code I can only have the depth = 2 allowed. What I want to do is to be able to print unlimited depth so I looked at my original function and I felt like re-designing it with recursion will be appropriate. So I developed the following:

```
void rec_printn(NODE *handle, int tab)   //unlimited depths
    {

    printf("tab %d\n", tab); //for testing purposes
    NODE *copy_handle = handle;
    for( ; copy_handle != NULL ; copy_handle = copy_handle->pNext )
        {
        printf("%*s|-> [ID: %d] %s\n", tab, " ",  copy_handle->id, copy_handle->pLabel);   //add variable spacing 

        if(copy_handle->pInner != NULL )
            {
            tab+=5;
            rec_printn(copy_handle->pInner , tab);
            }
        else if(copy_handle->pNext == NULL )
            {
            tab-=5;
            printf("<take back the indent\n"); //for testing purposes
            }

        }
    }
```

The trouble I'm having here is that the indents are not coming back as I would expect them in my original example above and instead I'm getting the following:

```
tab 5
     |-> [ID: 3] Poetry
tab 10
          |-> [ID: 3] Notes 3
          |-> [ID: 2] Notes 2
          |-> [ID: 1] Notes 1
<take back the indent
          |-> [ID: 2] Diet
tab 15
               |-> [ID: 2] Diet 2
               |-> [ID: 1] Diet 1
<take back the indent
               |-> [ID: 1] Program
<take back the indent
```

**Question : What am I doing wrong that the indents are not as they should be ?**

Comment: You are always incrementing by 5 before calling, so the `tab-=5` gets cancelled out. A quick fix would be to do `tab-=10;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding 5 to `tab` on each iteration.

Instead of mutating `tab`, pass the correct value to the function and let the recursion handle it:

```
if (copy_handle->pInner != NULL)
{
    rec_printn(copy_handle->pInner, tab + 5);
}
else if (copy_handle->pNext == NULL )
{
    printf("<take back the indent\n");
}
```

This will make sure that `tab` always has the same value for "this level".

(That is, instead of thinking "increase the indentation, then print the next level", think "print the next level with a deeper indentation", if you get what I mean.)

Comment: Fantastic! Solved my issue. I would have thought that the function wouldn't "remember" it's previous tab level and I don't fully understand why it does ?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer Each invocation of the function has its own variable called "tab", and they are completely independent.  (It works exactly like it would if you were calling a completely different function non-recursively - nothing would happen even if it happened to have a local variable or parameter called "tab".) Since you never assign a new value to `tab` on "this level", it doesn't change.

Comment: Ohh I get it now , thank you. As an aside and curiosity question: Would I have been able to do it without recursion ? the main problem I had was that pointer addresses were overwritten after printing the list and the list came out corrupted after that, hence the reason I used separate variables for each depth in my first example.

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer It could be done, but it would be messy, as your "list" is actually a tree. Iterative tree traversal usually involves managing your own stack of values instead of letting the machine do it for you by way of parameter-passing.